# Problems with Highcharts exporting server: Encoding and quality

Tags: highcharts, phantomjs

We are using our own export server to export charts from Highcharts. We followed the steps detailed on Highcharts website (see [here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server)). We're using the second option, the export server based on Java and PhantomJS (1.9.2) on a Windows 2008r2 server, with Tomcat 6 and Java RE 1.7.0.45.

Our export server works, but we are faced with 2 important problems:

1. Accentuated characters are displayed as squares on the exported charts. Everything is in UTF-8 on the HTML page from where charts are exported. When using export.highcharts.com as the exporting server, we don't have this problem.
2. Text on exported charts is blurry and has jagged edges. Again, when using export.highcharts.com as the exporting server, we don't have this problem.

Both problems can be seen by comparing the attached pics. The first one was exported using export.highcharts.com, and the second one using our exporting server.

[image: Export using Highcharts server] [image: Export using our server]

What is causing this and how can we fix it?

Comment: Definately it looks like a problem with UTF-encoding, could you reproduce it as live demo, or send us your html file with chart?

Comment: It's currently on a development server not accessible to the outside world. Maybe wergeld's server, who has the same problem as us, can be used. Using this jsFiddle with our export server (configuration stated above) shows the issue:  jsfiddle.net/jmunger/99wkv/2

Comment: I run your jsfiddle and all marks are exported correct, as I see

Comment: Yes, the jsFiddle will export correctly when using Highcharts servers. But not on ours. We followed the steps detailed on the Highcharts site. See the discussion with wergeld below: he's having the same problem with his exporting server.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure the fonts you are using on the webserver are also on the export server. What versions of the export server and Highhcharts are you using?

Comment: We've tried various regular fonts (Verdana, Arial, Times) that are already installed on the server.

Comment: We're using Highcharts v3.0.7.

Comment: I would also check which version of PhatomJS you have.

Comment: Latest version of PhantomJS (1.9.2).

Comment: Can you put up a JSfiddle example? I will try and hit our export server (3.0.6).

Comment: Verified this turns the text into garbage using our 3.0.6 HC export server as well. Not cool.

Comment: What is the version used on export.highcharts.com ? Do you also get the encoding problem?

Comment: I believe it is latest - 3.0.7. But they may be using something from Master. I am not sure. Yes, I get the same result you do - garbled characters with the "question mark diamond".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41207/discussion-between-the-jakester-and-wergeld)